# Getting an error while creating an asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
//global
private AsyncTask<String,String,String> myAsync;

//inside my activity
public class Myreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String arg[] = {intent.getStringExtra("id")};
        myAsync= new AsyncTask<String, String, String>(); //error here
        myAsync.execute(arg);
    }
}
```

The error is :

> Cannot instantiate the type AsyncTask

why ?

Comment: public **[abstract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)** class AsyncTask extends Object {...}

Comment: when added I got the following error : Illegal modifier for the field myAsync; only public, protected, private, static, final, 
 transient & volatile are permitted

Comment: AsyncTask is abstract, please read java to understand why you cannot instantiate a abstract class. And even worse @Dhaval, advices on calling a method of a class that has not be instantiated (comment out the line) what crap..

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html and you'll know why you can't instantiate your "AsyncTask" and why you get that error message.

Comment: After that read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html which also contains sample code on how to use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Its a sample AsyncTask Activity..

```
public class StockWatch extends Activity {


String myData;
Button refresh;
myHtmlParser myParser;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    refresh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    myParser = new myHtmlParser();   
    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            myAsyncTask myWebFetch = new myAsyncTask();
            myWebFetch.execute();
        }
    });
}

class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>    {

    TextView tv;

    myAsyncTask()    {
        //default constructor
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //do your stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //do your stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
          //do your stuff
    }   
}
```

}

for more details see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)